# Array addressing in AT&T GAS assembly. Register offset from RIP doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att, gnu-assembler, addressing-mode

I'm trying to work with arrays in GNU assembly. In my opinion the following code must exit with value 3. But it exits with 13.

```
.section __DATA,__data
  inArr:
    .word 13, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

  outArr:
    .fill 10, 2
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _main
_main:


  movq $3, %rcx

  movw inArr(%rip, %rcx, 2), %di  # load  *((rcx * 2)+ rip + &inArray) into %di, isn't it?
  movl $0x2000001, %eax           # exit
  syscall
```

In my opinion `movw inArr(%rip, %rcx, 2), %di` command is equivalent to something like `%di = inArr[%rcx]`. Unfortunately I can't find any examples with array in GAS.

What's wrong with that code? And how shall I address n-th element of array?

Comment: If you don't need position-independent code, you can use `movzwl inArr( ,%rcx, 2), %edi`.  But you probably *do* need PIC for OS X

Comment: Thank you!
That gives following error `error: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode`. 
I can't find what is PIC for OS X. Can you clarify this?

Comment: PIC = position-independent code.  You can't use absolute addressing on OS X in x86-64 code on OS X at all.  ([Unlike Linux.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing as indexed RIP-relative addressing mode. Your assembler should give an error. Use this instead:

```
    lea inArr(%rip), %rdi
    movzwl (%rdi, %rcx, 2), %edi
```

Comment: You can use `%rdi` for the pointer to avoid needing a tmp register.  (Unless the OP really did want to merge the word into the low 16 bits of RDI).

Comment: @Peter, yes, I used rax because the original code reloaded it in the next line. But the exit system call only uses the low 8 bits of rdi, so it was equally safe, and more likely to be the best choice without the context.

Comment: Thank you! It works. But it still very weird for me. In my opinion your code is working in the same way. I'm using GAS on OS X and it doesn't give me any error, just ignoring indexing. Maybe you can give me some links about arrays in GAS?

Comment: Documentation on the syntax: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html - also [How do RIP-relative variable references like "\[RIP + \_a\]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54745872)