# Assembly instruction reading, leaq

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

So I'm trying to compute the values of M and N in the following code with the assembly code given.

```
int array1[M][N];
int array2[N][M];

void copyelement(int i, int j) {
    array1[i][j] = array2[j][i];
}
```

Assembly:

```
copyelement:
    movslq      %esi, %rsi
    movslq      %edi, %rdi
    leaq        (%rdi,%rdi,8), %rax
    addq        %rsi, %rax
    leaq        (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rdx
    leaq        (%rsi,%rdx,4), %rdx
    addq        %rdx, %rdi
    leaq        array2(%rip), %rdx
    movl        (%rdx,%rdi,4), %ecx
    leaq        array1(%rip), %rdx
    movl        %ecx, (%rdx,%rax,4)
    ret
```

While reading through the assembly code, I got through till `array2(%rip)` and then I didn't know how to move forward.

At this point, according to my calculations I should have
`%rdx = %rdi + (%rsi + %rax) + 4*((%rsi+%rax) + 2*(%rsi + %rax))`.

Also I'm not quite sure how I would be able to get the array size from this.

Comment: Don't vandalize your questions by removing the asm.  It's not useful as an example for future readers without that.

Comment: For everyone confused by the %rip in array(%rip) look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy) or read about RIP relative addressing. In short, if array is in .data section then array(%rip) evaluates to the address of array without actually adding the %rip (just confusing notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got through till `array2(%rip)` and then I didn't know how to move forward.

Using that instruction, the address of `array2` (or `array2[0][0]`) is written to the `rdx` register. Forget about the `rip` register here.

The combination of that instruction plus the following one (`movl`) will read the array element `((int *)array2)[rdi]`. The two instructions following will write the array element `((int *)array1)[rax]`.

This means that `rdi` contains the value `M*j+i` and `rax` contains the value `N*i+j`.

If the code has been compiled for System-V, `rdi` initally contained the value of `i` and `rsi` initially contained the value of `j`.

**EDIT**

> okay I tried again, but I can't retrieve the exact value of M and N because the registers don't have any values loaded :/ am I missing something?

First we check with `i=0, j=1`:

This means that `edi` is initially `0` and `esi` is initially `1`.

If I did not make a mistake, `rdi` is 13 before the `leaq array2 ...` instruction.

This means that `M*j+i = M*1+0 = M = 13`.

Then we check with `i=1, j=0`.

If I did not make a mistake, `rax` is 9 before the `leaq array2 ...` instruction.

This means that `N*i+j = N*1+0 = N = 9`.

Comment: hm I see, thank you. So I can't exactly get a value for M and N? I assumed maybe the offset value gave some information. It was complied on a x86_64 machine running Linux if it helps

Comment: okay I tried again, but I can't retrieve the exact value of M and N because the registers don't have any values loaded :/ am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the instructions with annotations saying what they do.

```
// Initially, edi contains i and esi contains j.

movslq %esi, %rsi          // Sign-extend 32-bit j to 64 bits.
movslq %edi, %rdi          // Sign-extend 32-bit i to 64 bits.
leaq   (%rdi,%rdi,8), %rax // rax = rdi + rdi*8 = 9*rdi = 9*i.
addq   %rsi, %rax          // rax = rax + rsi = 9*i + j.
leaq   (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rdx // rdx = rsi + rsi*2 = 3*rsi = 3*j.
leaq   (%rsi,%rdx,4), %rdx // rdx = rsi + rdx*4 = j + (3*j)*4 = 13*j.
addq   %rdx, %rdi          // rdi = rdi + rdx = i + 13*j = i + 13*j.
leaq   array2(%rip), %rdx  // rdx = array2 (address of first element).
movl   (%rdx,%rdi,4), %ecx // Load *(rdx + rdi*4) = array2[rdi] = array2[i + 13*j] into ecx.
leaq   array1(%rip), %rdx  // rdx = array1 (address of first element).
movl   %ecx, (%rdx,%rax,4) // Store ecx into (rdx + rax*4) = array1[rax] = array1[9*i + j].
```

Thus `array2[j][i]` in the C code is `array2[i + 13*j]` in the assembly code (making allowances for two-dimensional addressing versus one-dimensional addressing). The latter should be `array2[i + M*j]`, so we can conclude `M` is 13.

Similarly, `array1[i][j]` in the C code is `array1[9*i + j]` in the assembly code. The latter should be `array1[N*i + j]`, so we can conclude `N` is 9.