# nasm: "symbol rip is undefined" - how to use lea-instruction relative to "rip" register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, addressing-mode, position-independent-code

I'd like to use the instruction `lea rax, [rip + 0x1020304]` with NASM but it seems like it doesn't allow that use of `rip`.

GAS (GNU Assembler) does allow this syntax for both numbers and symbols ([How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy)). How can I achieve this with NASM?

Comment: nasm uses the `rel` keyword but apparently you can't apply that to numerical absolute address. Normally it would look like `lea rax, [rel foo]`. If you really must, you can use a workaround along the lines of `lea rax, [rel $+0x1020304+7]`